# Finding index of div element within another div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need a simple script that would alert me with index number of certain div within a div.

Hovering over first box gives it's index (0) then another gives 1,2,3 etc.
Result I'm looking for is so third and fourth .box div would give their indexes within .box-container so 0 then 1 and not index of them within whole document. How would I approach such task? I know my code is close just not close enough.

```js
$(".box").mouseover(function() {
  console.log($(".box").index($(this)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">0</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>

<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.box').index($this)` -> `$(this).index()`

Comment: i posted same answer @RoryMcCrossan is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching `.box` class specific `index()` function to get index of element. There is issue due to its getting incremental ways index of element.

if you do using `$this` their `index()` it works.

Below is example :

```js
$(".box").mouseover(function() {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">0</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>

<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Added details.

Comment: The result I was looking for is 0,1,0,1 (cause boxes marked as 2 and 3 are in separate .box-container - and it's an index of them within that .box-container I need)

Comment: It’s give index of element which is hover box class